# Can a standard JPEG file format be abused to create lossless or uncompressed files?

Tags: jpeg

I am aware that producing JPEG files results in lossy compression, and that there is a lossless JPEG format, but I actually wonder if the standard JPEG format can be "hacked" in a certain way that allows it to store uncompressed pixels.

One seemingly possible way I have found is decreasing the MCU size from 8x8 to 1x1. If the format itself allowed such a change, would the color information remain unchanged for the whole image, or would the compression algorithm still mess with it?

Comment: You're free to disable color subsampling (4:4:4) and use quantization tables of all 1's, but there will still be some modification to the pixel values due to limited precision of the DCT and potential colorspace conversions. This will generate huge files and basically defeat the purpose of JPEG compression. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @BitBank So, basically, if the color space of the source bitmap matched the DCT precision, the image can be stored in this way without any loss? I suppose the coversion to Y′CBCR can be turned off. And yes, this is what I am looking for. Just a curiosity.

Comment: There is Lossless JPEG 2000 (.jp2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG Paint.net can save to this format. However it's not basic jpg if that is what your meant by 'standard'.

Comment: @borisdj As I said, I know this exists and it is not what I mean by "standard".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what you do you are going to get some attempt at compression and some loss in "standard" jpeg. The would be the case even if you set all your quantization tables to {1, 1, ....} and did not subsample.

You are going to get "loss" during the RGB => YCbCr transformation. You get going to get additional loss in the DCT.

Comment: It seems the RGB => YCbCr conversion can be skipped. If so, can you elaborate on the nature of the loss in the DCT? Does it affect only individual pixels, i.e. does it limit the number of colors, for example?

Comment: In both cases, you do floating point arithmetic and store the result in integer values.For the YCbcr conversion, you also have the problem that there is not a 1:1 mapping of the colorspaces.